# Opening Bootstrap Modal window On iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I would like to open a modal dialog of an iframe. When a user clicks the button should load the URL and pop up the URL content as a Modal.

However, for some reasons, this fails as shown on the code below. I am borrowing the idea from this http://jsfiddle.net/limeric29/C3LkL/

The example uses JQuery 1.8 but I would want to use 3.3. I suspect that's the reason for the failure.

```js
$('a.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $(".modal-body").html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" src="'+url+'"></iframe>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn" href="http://www.bing.com" data-target="#myModal">click me</a>
 
 
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone lead me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <a id="zoe" href="https://www.bing.com" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Click Me</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<script>
$('#zoe').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $(".modal-body").html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" src="'+url+'"></iframe>');
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```